# Qt images don't display in deployed app

Tags: qt

I deployed an app almost successfully because the images don't show up. Here is what I did:

1. created C:\Deployment
2. copied the release version of MyApp.exe to C:\Deployment
3. copied all the .dll files from C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\bin to C:\Deployment
4. copied all the folders from C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\plugins\ to C:\Deployment

The program runs fine but missing 2 images one displayed on a label and another on a button.

I also tried creating C:\Deployment\qml\MyApp folder in which I moved the images following the direction in the link below with no success.

https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows

Comment: Probably paths to image files in your code are incorrect

Comment: When I run the app in debug mode, all images display. When I run as release is when I have the problem.

Comment: @WhatIf You must use absolute paths to all files. You can build these paths on top of `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath`, of course - that's probably what you want. My bet is you didn't do that and are using relative paths. **Working directory in your application is unknown and cannot be presumed to be useful unless it's a command line application!**

Comment: Well, I created the app using Qt Designer. After creating the label, I clicked the pixmap and browsed to the image I wanted to use. When I move the mouse pointer over the image, it displays the complete path to the image. Could it be anything else?